# Find results with grep and write to file

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I would like to get all the results with `grep` or `egrep` from a file on my computer.

Just discovered that the regex of finding the string

`'+33. ... ... ..'` is by the following regex

`\+33.[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].'` *Or is this not correct?*

My `grep` command is:

```
grep '\+31.[0-9].[0.9].[0.9].[0-9]' Samsung\ GT-i9400\ Galaxy\ S\ II.xry  >> resultaten.txt
```

The output file is only giving me as following:

```
"Binary file Samsung GT-i9400 .xry matches"
```

..... and no results were given.

Can someone help me please with getting the results and writing to a file?

Comment: What the dot in your string means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the default behavior of `grep` is to print the *line* containing a match.  Because binary files do not contain lines, it only prints a message when it finds a match in a binary file.  However, this can be overridden with the `-a` flag.

But then, you end up with the problem that the "lines" it prints are not useful.  You probably want to add the `-o` option to only print the substrings which actually matched.

Finally, your regex isn't correct at all.  The lone dot `.` is a metacharacter which matches any character, including a control character or other non-text character.  Given the length of your regex, you are unlikely to catch false positives, but you might want to explain what you want the dot to match.  I have replaced it with `[ ._-]` which matches a space and some punctuation characters which are common in phone numbers.  Maybe extend or change it, depending on what interpunction you expect in your phone numbers.

In regular `grep`, a plus simply matches itself.  With `grep -E` the syntax would change, and you would need to backslash the plus; but in the absence of this option, the backslash is superfluous (and actually wrong in this context in some dialects, including GNU `grep`, where a backslashed plus selects the extended meaning, which is of course a syntax error at beginning of string, where there is no preceding expression to repeat one or more times; but GNU `grep` will just silently ignore it, rather than report an error).

On the other hand, your number groups are also wrong.  `[0-9]` matches a *single* digit, where apparently the intention is to match multiple digits.  For convenience, I will use the `grep -E` extension which enables `+` to match one or more repetitions of the previous character.  Then we also get access to `?` to mark the punctuation expressions as optional.

Wrapping up, try this:

```
grep -Eao '\+33[0-9]+([^ ._-]?[0-9]+){3}' \
   'Samsung GT-i9400 Galaxy S II.xry' >resultaten.txt
```

In human terms, this requires a literal `+33` followed by required additional digits, then followed by three number groups of one or more digits, each optionally preceded by punctuation.

This will overwrite `resultaten.txt` which is usually what you want; the append operation you had also makes sense in many scenarios, so change it back if that's actually what you want.

If each dot in your template `+33. ... ... ..` represents a required number, and the spaces represent required punctuation, the following is closer to what you attempted to specify:

```
\+33[0-9]([^ ._-][0-9]{3}){2}[^ ._-][0-9]{2}
```

That is, there is one required digit after 33, then two groups of exactly three digits and one of two, each group preceded by one non-optional spacing or punctuation character.

(Your exposition has `+33` while your actual example has `+31`.  Use whichever is correct, or perhaps allow any sequence of numbers for the country code, too.)

Answer (score 1):

It means that you're find a match but the file you're `grep`ing isn't a text file, it's a binary containing non-printable bytes.  If you really want to grep that file, try:

```
strings Samsung\ GT-i9400\ Galaxy\ S\ II.xry | grep '+31.[0-9].[0.9].[0.9].[0-9]' >> resultaten.txt
```

Comment: This still doesn't address the problems with the regex; it will probably find some  matches, but not exactly the intended ones.